# Webpack output multiple scss files (one compiled and one not compiled)

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

Is it possible to configure webpack so that it outputs an uncompiled scss file alongside compiled scss?

I'm looking to expose scss variables, mixins, and functions this way.

**files:**

```
styles/
  index.scss
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: "./lib/index.css",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: require.resolve("sass-loader"),
            options: {
              warnRuleAsWarning: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: ["../../node_modules"],
                outputStyle: "compressed",
                outFile: path.resolve(__dirname, "./lib/index.css"),
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".css", ".scss"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    library: {
      type: "umd",
      name: "design-system",
    }
  }
};
```

**example output:**

```
lib/
  index.css (compiled version)
  index.scss (uncompiled version)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's impossible unless you use a different plugin for it, so I would recommend to use [`copy-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) in this use case.

```js
// npm i -D copy-webpack-plugin
// yarn add -D copy-webpack-plugin

const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "./styles/index.scss", to: "./lib/" },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: always another package am I right? lol Thank you very much for the time and help